# Regex is throwing an error when I use square brackets?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm getting this when using square brackets in a regex string:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
   what():   regex_error
```

The following program runs fine:

```
#include <regex>
int main()
{
    std::regex rx1("a");
    return 0;
}
```

But this does not:

```
#include <regex>
int main()
{
    std::regex rx1("[a]");
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, and I couldn't find any examples of this happening to anybody else, so I'm really stumped here. I'm quite new to c++, so I could be missing something blindingly obvious, but could anybody explain what's up?

edit--

So I recompiled with ms visual c++ 2010 (I was using GCC) and it didn't throw any errors. I'm not familiar with the differences between compilers, though, and I don't know which I should/shouldn't be using. Is there a generally accepted "best" compiler?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? My money's on GCC, it's been known to lack a lot of regex features.

Comment: GCC, yeah. I'll try with another compiler, and see how that goes.

Comment: I'm running GCC (tdm-1) 4.7.1